# Python - Building a string from a loop

Tags: python, string

I have a set of points that have latitude and longitude values and I am trying to create a string in the following format in order to work with the Gmaps API:

```
 LatitudeX,LongitudeX|LatitudeY,LongitudeY
```

The final string will be built using an unknown number of lat long pairs.

My previous experience is with PHP and, whilst I have managed to get something working however, it seems a bit clumsy and I was wondering if there as a more 'pythonic' way to achieve the result.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 waypoints = ''

 for point in points:
     waypoints = waypoints+"%s,%s" % (point.latitude, point.longitude)+"|"

 waypoints = waypoints[:-1]
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html):

```
waypoints = '|'.join("{0},{1}".format(p.latitude, p.longitude) for p in points)
```

Comment: Also note the use of a generator expression (+1 btw). Never use a list comprehension when a generator expression works.

Comment: The join method on strings is one of the fastest ways to concatenate strings. @Dan Check out http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ for examples... and note that the naive concatenation with the + operator has terrible performance compared with str.join.